# System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes Extra Byte

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, utf-8, character-encoding

Why does this line

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ABCD±ABCD")
```

Give me back 10 bytes instead of 9?
Although ± is char(177)

Is there a .Net function / encoding that will translate this string **correctly** into 9 bytes?

Comment: "correctly" depends very much on what the "correct" encoding is. If your intention is to use UTF-8, then : there is no way of "correctly" encoding it into 9 bytes. If your intent is to use ***some*** encoding to get it into 9 bytes, you need to decide up front on what code-page-based encoding you want to use, and why, and what you are going to do for data that isn't defined in that code-page.

Comment: This video explains utf-8 encoding nicely: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4. After watching it you will realize why it results in more bytes and you thought.

Comment: Definition of "correctly": with the ability to translate it back from byte to original character. Example: ASCII encoding will not do this correctly although it will be limited to my expected 9 chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Windows-1251` encoding to get `±` as `177`

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetBytes("ABCD±ABCD");
```

Comment: +1, but you should explain why it might work as he expects with Windows-1251 and not UTF-8.

Comment: and then watch the fireworks when someone tries to encode something outside 0xFF...

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. And I totally understand that anything outside of 0xFF cannot be encoded into a single byte. It would have been a perfect answer if you had explained how UTF8 works. The video link posted by @user2316005 below explains it really well.

Answer (score 8):

> Although ± is char(177)

And the UTF-8 encoding for that is 0xc2 0xb1 - two bytes. Basically, every code-point >= 128 will take multiple bytes - where the number of bytes depends on the magnitude of the code-point.

That data **is 10 bytes**, when encoded with UTF-8. The error here is your expectation that it should take 9.

Comment: Definition of "correctly": with the ability to translate it back from byte to original character. Example: ASCII encoding will not do this correctly although it will be limited to my expected 9 chars.

Comment: I guess I expected UTF8 to simply use 8bits per character (as the name implies -- at least to me), that's all.

Answer (score 2):

`±` falls out side of the range of ASCII so it is represented by 2 bytes.