# Java - Why String( a).getBytes() == a not give the same result?

Tags: java

For an example array:

```
byte[] arr = {37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -30, -29, -49, -45, -121, -104 };
```

And the code:

```
String a = new String(arr, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"))));
System.out.println( Arrays.equals(arr, a.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"))) );
```

The result is:

- In "Windows-1251":

  ```
  [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -30, -29, -49, -45, -121, -104]
  [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -30, -29, -49, -45, -121, 63]
  false
  ```
- In "US-ASCII":

  ```
  [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -30, -29, -49, -45, -121, -104]
  [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63]
  false
  ```
- In "UTF-8":

  ```
  [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -30, -29, -49, -45, -121, -104]
  [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -45, -121, -17, -65, -67]
  false
  ```

I have test with various test case and found that they give different arrays when there are negative number. And I tried with "Windows-1251" like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036870/system-text-encoding-utf8-getbytes-extra-byte) but the arrays still different.
So my question is:

- Why?
- How to fix it?

Addtional Info:

- I'm using JRE8 and on Windows 8.1.

Resolution: Use Charset ISO-8859-1, thank to SLaks for explaining and JB Nizet for point out the ISO-8859-1

```
String a = new String(arr, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))));
System.out.println( Arrays.equals(arr, a.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))) );
```

Result:

```
[37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -30, -29, -49, -45, -121, -104]
[37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 53, 13, 37, -30, -29, -49, -45, -121, -104]
true
```

Comment: Have you tried `equals` method??

Comment: @VighaneshGursale: Read his code.

Comment: @SLaks oops my mistake you were correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

63 is the codepoint for `?`.
The decoder will return a `?` for every byte that is not valid in that encoding.

For `US-ASCII`, that includes every byte above 127.

For `UTF-8`, that includes every byte above 127 which does not follow proper UTF8 rules.

Comment: Um! So what Charset will suffice for all possible byte value?

Comment: @Tr1et: What are you trying to accomplish? This sounds like a mistake.  Consider using Base64.

Comment: I'm trying to save a byte[] in a String in raw form, not Arrays.toString(), and I can take it out later, but I dont know what Charset I should use to store it as.

Comment: AFAIK, the only encoding that is completely reversible is ISO-8859-1: each byte represents a valid character. But that doesn't mean it's a good idea to treat binary data as characters. Keep it as a byte or, if you really need it as a printable String, use Base64.

Comment: I need to store into String so I can send it in a Stream. Thank you, I successed with ISO-8859-1, can you write it into the answer for easier access too.

Comment: A better solution would be to use a Base64 encoder/decoder - this is what they were created for. In Java 8 there is one in java.util - for older versions Apache has one.

Comment: In the paper I should send a Header, then raw binary data, then the Footer, but I think that if I can store the raw data into the String, I can send it all in one step using BufferedWriter. About the Base64, I'm afraid that the other end won't use it. Maybe I'll ask them about it later.